# equals override being called for no reason

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, overriding

I have the below pieces of code.  For some reason, when the "CellMouseDown" event is fired, it appears to call the "Equals" method twice for every row in my grid.

I made a slew of changes recently, and apparently one of them caused this situation, but there's no way for me to back out of the changes at this point.

The problem is that I'm getting an invalid cast exception because "obj" is not of type "DataSource" at this point (which wouldn't matter if this wasn't getting fired, which it shouldn't be).

Can anyone think of a reason why the "Equals" is getting called when the "CellMouseDown" fires (and is happening so many times)?

Thanks,

Andrew

```
    private void gridDataSources_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // this is so I can select the current row when you right-click to change the color
        if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            this.gridDataSources.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
            this.gridDataSources.CurrentCell = this.gridDataSources.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        DataSource original = (DataSource)obj;

        // code removed for brevity

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Well why don't you look at the stack trace? That will give you a very good hint as to what's going on. But fundamentally, your implementation is broken, because it should just return `false` when given a non-DataSource. From the docs: "Implementations of Equals must not throw exceptions; they should always return a value."

Comment: First, the stack trace doesn't give me any details at all.  I'm not sure why, but it's as if nothing else is called before that.

Also, if I put a try/catch around the "Equals", then I get:

Position is either less than 0 or greater than the number of items in the data source.

on the line:

this.gridDataSources.CurrentCell = this.gridDataSources.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

which makes no sense to me either.  :(

Comment: Are you clicking on a new row (the one at the bottom with *) cell?

Comment: No, an existing row.

Comment: Is the grid data bound? What is the type of the data source (i.e. List, BindingList etc.)?

Comment: Have you looked at what reference is being passed as the argument?

Comment: It is bound, to a BindingList of a custom class (DataSourceModel).  The argument being passed to the "Equals" method is the "DataSourceModel" of the line I clicked on.  But I don't understand why that method is being called when I click on it, that didn't happen before.

Comment: As @JonSkeet mentioned, look at the Call Stack window (make sure "Show External Code" is selected). I was able to get `Equals` call only when clicking on a new row, and call was from BindingList IndexOf method.

Comment: The only things I see there are related to the BindingList tool I'm using (Equin.ApplicationFramework.BindingListView.dll), which doesn't appear to have come with the PDB file, so I can't step into that.  :(

Comment: Well that's the first you've mentioned of that - it sounds like it would be worth asking the authors of that.

Comment: I would agree except that it has to be related to something I changed, since it was working before.  I just thought maybe someone had seen something similar in the past and might know what some possible causes are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, the Equin BindingListView uses an object's "Equals" method internally.  Now I'm not sure why this was never an issue before, since the problem is bad coding on my part and it's been like that (not one of the changes I'd mentioned).  Turns out I was overriding the "Equals" method on my custom class, but I was actually comparing 2 different object types.  One being my custom class (the model) and the other being the actual entity.  I'm comparing these to each other to determine whether I need to write a history entry (or even save anything, since if it's not different, then why bother), but I'm comparing apples to oranges, which isn't really something you should do in an override of the "Equals" method.